# React - create http request from JSON schema

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http

I am trying to find a package with a method that can take JSON object which describe the request like-

```
{
   "url":"https://whatever/data/api", //end point
   "body":"{"xyz":"123"}",
   "method":"POST", //GET, PUT....
   "headers":"xy...."
}
```

and will create the matching http request.

Comment: I don't think that's valid JSON. Does [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) not do the job?

Comment: Thanks for the response @evolutionxbox, the comments in the json are just for more information.

Comment: I’m glad you commented, but even without the comments it’s still not valid.